# Max Hamming Distance

Tags: java, arrays, time-complexity

I needed to write a method that can calculate the maximum hamming distance between a given array and a rotation of that array.

My code :

```
public static int maxHamming(int[] arr, int n) {
    HashSet hs = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        hs.add(arr[i]);
    }
    return hs.size();
}
```

n is the length of the array.

The problem is that on [GeeksforGekks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-a-rotation-with-maximum-hamming-distance/) the solution given is O(n*n) so I don't know if my solution is actually correct since it works quicker. I've tested it with their examples and it works but I don't have more test cases to try before I'll have to submit it, and I'm unsure if this works for any given array.

Comment: your solution is incorrect, but you can still do it in ```O(n)``` time complexity and use a ```HashMap``` https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-a-rotation-with-maximum-hamming-distance-set-2/

Comment: @NeonFire oh yeah I missed the part where the length of the array is 1 or when all the ints are the same. But I don't understand why I need to use Hashmap instead of Hashset.

Comment: you can use either to be honest, as they both provide (typically) O(1) element access